# Is the new border crossing between Georgia and Turkey at Kartsakhi open to foreigners?

Tags: regulations, borders, turkey, georgia-country, land-borders

I was just reading a Quora post on [the longest overland trip in the world](http://www.quora.com/What-cross-country-route-is-the-longest-road-trip-in-the-world) and it mentions crossing from Georgia to Turkey at Kartsakhi. I've crossed between these countries probably half a dozen times and used both crossings I knew of. But the last time was in 2012 I think.

So I did some searching and [found an article on the opening of the border checkpoint](http://www.police.ge/en/shinagan-saqmeta-ministrma-sasazghvro-seqtori-/6946), but it doesn't mention whether people who are neither Georgian nor Turkish are permitted to cross.

(It's only a couple of months since I turned up at [a border crossing from Cambodia to Vietnam that everybody thought I could cross and found out it's only for locals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44856/140). So I'm pretty sure this is common for crossings in various parts of the world.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!** It opened in October 2015:
[image: Border now open image]

[Official Georgian announcement.](http://www.mof.ge/en/News/6976)

I learned of this and borrowed the image from [a post on Quora about interesting border crossings](http://qr.ae/RgFI16).

Answer (score 5):

I have not been able to find any restrictions on the border crossing by foreigners on the Kartsakhi.

Actually the most news on the subject I was able to find on Russian and Azeri news sites specifically with respect to the [high speed rail project Baku-Tbilisi-Kars (Russian)](http://azertag.az/ru/xeber/Na_stancii_Karcahi_na_gruzino_tureckoi_granice_zapushchen_testovyi_poezd-828277) where Kartsakhi would be the border crossing station for rail traffic on the line.

On top of this Kartsakhi is being viewed as a means to improve [tourist flow into Georgia (Russian)](http://www.apsny.ge/2014/pol/1400996257.php), so I don't see them imposing the restrictions on foreigners entering the country to locals only after it's fully open given this view.